# Delete column from Vector<Vector<Short>>

Tags: java, matrix, vector

The function below must delete the row or column that I want, when deleting the row everything goes perfectly, I have an error in the column. The last update function is to update the file.

```
 public void deletefromfile() throws IOException {
        short mod;
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("0 - column ");
        System.out.println("1 - row");
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        mod = cin.nextShort();
        switch (mod) {
            case 0:
                // System.out.println("Number of column: ");


                short col = cin.nextShort(); // column to be deleted
                Short w;
                for(int line = 0; line < A.size(); line++) {
                        w = A.get(lini).get(col); // w becomes the number in the required column
                    System.out.print(w + " "); // display the column to be deleted 
                    A.remove(w); }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(A); // display the vector to see if it has been deleted


                break;


                //m--;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Numarul randului: ");
                short rand = cin.nextShort();
                A.remove(rand);
                System.out.println(A);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Introduceti un mod valid");
        }
        cin.close();
        update();
    }
```

Vector<Vector> A; -> declare of vector (sorry for my english)

My file is:

4 4

2 9 4 1

9 10 25 14

19 18 35 1

1 2 3 8

Comment: No matter, the solution was:
for (Vector <Short> vec: A)
                     vec.remove (col);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use A.remove(lini).remove(col), not A.remove(w) ?

Comment: The matrix becomes

9 10 25 14 |

1 2 3 8

I need the number of rows to remain, the number of columns to decrease.